# How to Identify the Source of a Custom Field?

Tags: custom-field

A Wordpress installation I'm working with has a couple dozen custom fields, including some that contain outdated Open Graph information (e.g., dpsp_pinterest_hidden_images, swp_advanced_pinterest_image_location).

I'm trying to identify what created those custom fields, and/or what plugin or function is using them, in order to determine whether or not I can delete them.

Is there any way to do this?